# Mocked service does not disable button in angular test?

Tags: angular, ts-jest, angular-material-stepper, ts-mockito

I am using angular material stepper to navigate in my component have the below button:

Below is my stepper.component.html code
<button [disabled]="myService.disableNextButton(stepper.selectedIndex)"> Next

Then I have a service that uses a behaviorSubject to store productId:

```
export class MyService {

 product : any {
 productId: 0,
 ProductName: ''
}

private productDetails = new BehaviorSubject<ProductData>(this.product);

disableNextButton(step: number) : boolean{
  if(this.productDetails.value.productId==0){
return true;
}
return false;
}

}
```

I am using JEST test and ts-mockito to mock my service as per below:

```
product : any {
productId: 0,
ProductName: ''
}

private productDetails = new BehaviorSubject<ProductData>(this.product);

  const myServiceMock = mock(MyService);
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    when(MyService.disableNextButton(anything())).thenReturn(
      true
    );
    await render(StepperComponent, {
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MatStepperModule, MatButtonModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MyService,
          useFactory: () => instance(myServiceMock),
        }
      ]
    });
  });
```

In my test I have the below:

```
const nextButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'next' });
expect(nextButton).toBeDisabled();
```

The problem is when I use the original service, the button is disabled on start, but when I mock the service, it does not disable it. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entierly sure if the `when`/`thenReturn` syntax is ok. I usually would write that as `myServiceMock.disableNextButton.mockReturnValue(true)` or `myServiceMock.disableNextButton.mockReturnValueOnce(true)`.

also, in your `disableNextButton` function, just return `this.productDetails.value.productId == 0` instantly (useless if-clause).